# DFS Replicated Folder partial sync to 3rd member

Tags: sync, windows-server-2016, dfs

I have `DFS` configured on `Windows Server 2016` to sync a folder to our offsite DR server. This has been working for a number of years, flawlessly. The folder in question has roughly 100 subfolders.

We now want to sync only 3 of these sub-folders to a 3rd server at a branch office located elsewhere.

My initial thought was to set that subfolder up as its own replicated folder, but as I assumed, it failed because that folder is already being synced as part of another replicated folder.

Other than using `cwRsync` or similar tools, is there another way to achieve what I need? For one reason or another, which I won't go into here, we cannot sync the entire folder to this 3rd member server.

Comment: To whomever edited the question, you made it a different question that I know how to answer. It is specifically about a 3rd member server not syncing all folders if 2 other servers are syncing them all. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if you could pull out the 3 folders from the existing structure and then put those in a new folder not yet synced with DFS, put a junction point link using `mklink /?` pointing to the new locations that way for those that need to access from the first two servers, and then sync the DFS to the new structure parent folder for the three subfolders? Just a quick thought but otherwise native Windows `Robocopy /?` may work using task scheduler for automation, etc. Depending on which direction(s) you need to since depends on the sort of logic needed for the command. Otherwise, Powershell it.